# C# performance counter data is "all over the map"

Tags: c#, .net, performance, performancecounter

I need to calculate CPU and RAM usage for the overall system as well as for a specific process. I've never done this in C#. So I was able to come up with the following code (that I took primarily from samples on this web site):

```
try
{
    Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    string strProcName = proc.ProcessName;
    Console.WriteLine("Process: " + strProcName);

    using (PerformanceCounter total_cpu = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", "_Total", true))
    {
        using (PerformanceCounter process_cpu = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", strProcName, true))
        {
            for (; ; )
            {
                Console.CursorTop = 1;
                Console.CursorLeft = 0;

                float t = total_cpu.NextValue() / Environment.ProcessorCount;
                float p = process_cpu.NextValue() / Environment.ProcessorCount;
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Total CPU (%) = {0}\t\t\nApp CPU (%) = {1}\t\t\nApp RAM (KB) = {2}",
                    t, p, Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 / (1024)
                    ));

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex);
}
```

But what it gives me is the data "all over the map". Take a look:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So can someone answer these points:

1. It seems like running such performance counter is a pretty costly operation by itself -- it raises CPU usage by about 5%. I did a ton of CPU counters with C++ and they take pretty much no CPU time to run.
2. Besides what I said above, the first time the loop above runs with a **2 second delay**! It literally **hangs up for 2 seconds**. Is it normal? If it is, I can't believe they had an audacity to call it a *performance counter* :)
3. Even though my RAM reading is pretty close to the one reported by the Task Manager, the CPU output is totally off. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?
4. Moreover, I can't seem to find any documentation for the [PerformanceCounter class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t90y2y1.aspx), that can explain all of these: `% Processor Time`, `_Total`, etc? And most importantly, are those English only? Are they supposed to be localized?
5. The process there is specified by its name. But what if I have more than one process under the same name running. What then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with, but that is using unmanaged APIs:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetProcessTimes(IntPtr hProcess, out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME
    lpCreationTime, out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME lpExitTime, out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME lpKernelTime,
    out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME lpUserTime);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
static extern UInt32 GetTickCount();

static bool gbSetOldData = false;
static UInt32 gmsOldTickCount = 0;
static ulong gnsOldKernelTime = 0;
static ulong gnsOldUserTime = 0;

public static double getCPUUsageForProcess(int nProcID = 0)
{
    //Get CPU usage for the process in with ID in 'nProcID'
    //'nProcID' = process ID, or 0 for the current process
    //RETURN:
    //      = CPU usage: [0.0 - 1.0]
    //      = Negative if error
    double fCPUUsage = -1.0;
    try
    {
        IntPtr hProcess = nProcID != 0 ? Process.GetProcessById(nProcID).Handle : Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftCreated, ftExit, ftKernel, ftUser;
        if (GetProcessTimes(hProcess, out ftCreated, out ftExit, out ftKernel, out ftUser))
        {
            UInt32 dwmsNewTickCount = GetTickCount();

            ulong nsNewKernelTime = (ulong)ftKernel.dwHighDateTime;
            nsNewKernelTime <<= 32;
            nsNewKernelTime |= (ulong)(uint)ftKernel.dwLowDateTime;

            ulong nsNewUserTime = (ulong)ftUser.dwHighDateTime;
            nsNewUserTime <<= 32;
            nsNewUserTime |= (ulong)(uint)ftUser.dwLowDateTime;

            if (gbSetOldData)
            {
                //Adjust from 100-nanosecond intervals to milliseconds
                //100-nanosecond intervals = 100 * 10^-9 = 10^-7
                //1ms = 10^-3
                fCPUUsage = (double)((nsNewKernelTime - gnsOldKernelTime) + (nsNewUserTime - gnsOldUserTime)) /
                    (double)((dwmsNewTickCount - gmsOldTickCount) * 10000);

                //Account for multiprocessor architecture
                fCPUUsage /= Environment.ProcessorCount;

                //In case timer API report is inaccurate
                if (fCPUUsage > 1.0)
                    fCPUUsage = 1.0;
            }
            else
            {
                //For the first run, assume no CPU usage
                fCPUUsage = 0.0;
            }

            //Remember data
            gnsOldKernelTime = nsNewKernelTime;
            gnsOldUserTime = nsNewUserTime;
            gmsOldTickCount = dwmsNewTickCount;
            gbSetOldData = true;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //Failed
        fCPUUsage = -1.0;
    }

    return fCPUUsage;
}
```

And this is how you'd call it:

```
int nDummy = 1;

for (; ; )
{
    double fCPU = getCPUUsageForProcess();

    Console.CursorTop = 1;
    Console.CursorLeft = 0;

    int nCpu = (int)(fCPU * 100);
    Console.WriteLine("CPU%: {0}\t\t", nCpu);

    //Time filler
    long j = 0;
    for (; j < 1000000; j++)
    {
        nDummy += (int)Math.Cos(1 / (j + 1));
    }

    //Don't hog all CPU time!
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

I'm not sure if .NET has a similar method. If there's one (that doesn't have all the limitations I posted above) I'd like to hear it?

Answer (score 0):

> Your code seems fine but the total cpu usage counter is wrong. you
>   have process instead of processor. Also don't split the percentage like that since windows always uses the cpu that has the less load unless your app is made for multi threading. The other thing, is your sample, it's too fast. I slowed it down to 1 sec. you should have a better
>   feedback from the counter

```
try
{
    Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    string strProcName = proc.ProcessName;
    Console.WriteLine("Process: " + strProcName);

    using (PerformanceCounter total_cpu = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total", true))
    {
        using (PerformanceCounter process_cpu = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", strProcName, true))
        {
            for (; ; )
            {
                Console.CursorTop = 1;
                Console.CursorLeft = 0;

                float t = total_cpu.NextValue() ;
                float p = process_cpu.NextValue();
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Total CPU (%) = {0}\t\t\nApp CPU (%) = {1}\t\t\nApp RAM (KB) = {2}",
                    t, p, Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 / (1024)
                    ));

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex);
}
```